# Empty file uploaded

Tags: php

I want to send some images via POST and for some of them, they cannot be uploaded.
when I do `print_r($_FILES['imgs']);` I have:

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => myImage.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
```

I have tried modifying the max post and upload size in the php.ini file but it still not working and the images aren't big.
Also my form tag contains the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

here is the html form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body container">
                        <label for="titre" class="col-form-label" >Titre:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titre" style="font-size: 16px" name="title">
                        <label for="descr" class="col-form-label" >Description:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="descr" style="font-size: 16px" name="summary"></textarea>
                        <label for="img" style="width: 100%" class="col-form-label">Ajout d'image(s):</label>
                            <input type="file"  id="img" accept="image/*" multiple onchange="changeImageSet(this.files)" name="imgs[]">
                            <div id="imageList"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ajouter" name="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Post the related html form

Comment: Also , the PHP code have you tried to upload images

Comment: The output of `print_r($_FILES['imgs']);` suggests they *are* being uploaded. What makes you think they are not?

Comment: The error code of "1" suggests that the image is larger than your `upload_max_filesize` setting.

Answer (score 0):

tmp_name,size,error key check after upload image
for example

```
if(isset($_FILES["imgs"])){
  $img=$_FILES["imgs"];
 if($img["error"]===0){
    if($img["size"]>0){
       //  $upload=move_upload_file($img,"img/");
      //  use verot.net upload 
    }else{
     echo "Error File empty";
    }
  }else{
     echo "Error:".$img["error"];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using an older version of `php.ini` with parameters

```
; upload_max_filesize = 32M 
; post_max_size = 32M
```